# Adding TextArea and Colspan to dynamically created table row

Tags: javascript, html-table, textarea

I am having following hardcoded table data

```
 <td colspan="4">
   <textarea rows="4" cols="40"></textarea>
 </td>
```

but I want to do this thing using Javascript or jQuery can anyone tell me how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Just do it.

```
var td = document.createElement('td');

td.setAttribute('colspan', '4');

var textarea = document.createElement('textarea');

textarea.setAttribute('rows', '4');
textarea.setAttribute('cols', '40');

td.appendChild(textarea);
```